# itextsharp html to .pdf with vb.net

Tags: html, pdf, itext

I've been trying for the past 3 days to get itextsharp to convert a simple html table to pdf. I found a solution that used htmlworker but i'm needing some control over the css. I then tried to implement the xmlworker object and It's almost as if I'm not importing something i'm suppose to because whenever I get to this line:

```
    worker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, New StringReader(htmlReport))
```

I receive an the following errors:
"Value of type 'iTextSharp.text.Document' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'."

"Value of type 'System.IO.StringReader' cannot be converted to 'System.Text.Encoding'."

I've tried several different examples and I always wind up with these errors...the code that I have up to this point that is not functional is below. Any info as to why these errors keep coming up for me would be greatly appreciated :)

```
    Dim htmlReport As String = output.ToString

        'Convert to pdf
        Dim document As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 1, 1, 0, 0)
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Document, New FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\Export\test.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        document.Open()
        Dim worker As XMLWorkerHelper = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance
        worker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, New StringReader(htmlReport))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I discovered what the issue was and it was rather trivial but just in case anyone else runs into the same issue I'll explain what It was. I was using an older version of the base itextsharp.dll from the version of itextsharp.xmlworker.dll. Now I do not know that the versions must be the same, all I know is that you must make sure your version of .dll is current.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had this same EXACT problem, and the resolution was the same--wrong version of the DLL.